# How to start my JS countdown 2pm to 2pm?

Tags: javascript

Currently, it is working for 12am to 12am but I want it 2pm to 2pm. Is it possible?

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = 23 - d.getHours();
    var min = 59 - d.getMinutes();
    if ((min + '').length == 1) {
      min = '0' + min;
    }
    var sec = 59 - d.getSeconds();
    if ((sec + '').length == 1) {
      sec = '0' + sec;
    }
    $('#the-final-countdown').html(hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec);
  },
  1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="the-final-countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function time(){
      var d = new Date();
      if(d.getHours()<=13){
        var hours = (13 - d.getHours());
       }else{
         var hours = (23+14 - d.getHours())
       }
      var min = 59 - d.getMinutes();
      if((min + '').length == 1){
        min = '0' + min;
      }
      var sec = 59 - d.getSeconds();
      if((sec + '').length == 1){
            sec = '0' + sec;
      }
      jQuery('#the-final-countdown p').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: I think it is not working. can you please check https://codepen.io/limon213/pen/aEarrd

Comment: @KhandakerIkrama sorry i had calculated it all wrong now i hope it works perfectly

Comment: Thank you very much :) I also think it is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create a count down to 14:00 is to get the difference between now and the next time it will be 14:00, then convert to h:mm:ss, e.g.

```js
// Returns milliseconds from date until next 1400
// Default for date is current time
function next1400(date) {
  var now = date || new Date();
  var end = new Date(now);
  end.setHours(end.getHours() < 14? 14 : 38, 0, 0, 0);
  return formatTime(end - now);
}

// Format milliseconds as H:mm:ss
function formatTime(ms) {
  var s = Math.ceil(ms/1e3);
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return (s/3.6e3 | 0) + ':' +
         z((s%3.6e3)/60 | 0) + ':' +
         z(s%60) ;       
}

// QnD way to call each second. This will skip occasionally, 
// there are better ways.
setInterval(function(){
  console.log(next1400());
}, 1000);
```